# Controller Testing with Rspec in rails

Tags: rspec

I am new on Rails and Rspec.
My Rspec file is not taking a Controller's property(as-instance variable)

```
assigns[:portal_news].should be_new_record
```

It always gives the error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.new_record?
```

Can anyone find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're treating `assigns` as a hash, but it is a method that takes an argument: `assigns(:portal_news)`.

More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

Your controller method should be creating a new instance of your model and assigning it to @portal_news`, maybe something like this:

```
@portal_news = MyModel.new
```

We'll need to see the contents of the relevant controller method, and of the failing spec, to be able to help you figure this out.

Comment: In controller code :  @portal_news=PortalNews.new is mentioned .but portal_news variable could not access in portal_news_controller_spec file. Please find the solution

Comment: There are several possibilities. Do you have any `before_filter`s that could be preventing the assignment statement from being reached? Do you get the same error when trying to access the page in your browser?

Comment: thanks for reply. In controller i already commented all filters.but After that it still not working.I installed rspec(2.1.0) and rspec-rails(2.1.0) on rails 2.3.5

Comment: Please anyone find the solution